# Is there any combination $(+,-,/,\cdot,\sqrt{})$ of algebraic numbers , $a$ and $b$, that becomes transcedental?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I know the other way around is true, we can combine
transcendental numbers to create algebraic ones, for example: $\pi/\pi=1$ or $\pi-\pi=0$. But what if $a$ and $b$ are algebraic, is there any combination of $a$ and $b$ that creates a transcedental one?

I'm aware of the theorem that states that $a^b$ is transcedental for algebraic $a \neq 0$ and irrational $b$. $\ln a$, $\sin a$ are also trans. numbers.

So i'm talking about adding, substraction, roots, multiplication, division. For example $a \pm b, \sqrt{a\pm b}, \sqrt{a}/b$ etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a general way to find out whether a number obtained by a finite combination of algebraic operations is algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118682/what-is-a-general-way-to-find-out-whether-a-number-obtained-by-a-finite-combinat)

Comment: For $+,-,/,\cdot$ use that the algebraic numbers form a field. For the square root use that you can replace $x$ by $x^2$ in the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operations you have provided are all algebraic; the sum of two algebraic numbers is algebriac, the difference, the product, the quotient (assuming you don't divide by 0), and the square root of two algebraic numbers are also algebraic.

Thus, any finite string you write involving algebraic numbers and these operations will also be algebraic.

Comment: "The operations you have provided are all algebraic" is that a definition? what operations are non-algebreaic?

Comment: @Anon Exponents, i.e. $(a, b) \mapsto a^b$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

Comment: I'm sure there is an official definition out there, but I mean to use it in a manner that is just what followed after the semicolon. Those operations are closed on the set of algebraic numbers. Wikipedia doesn't have a good page on them, but here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_operation

Comment: Like @TheoBendit said, something like the exponential function, trig functions, logarithms, and other more exotic objects are called "transcendental functions" because they can't be expressed purely in terms of the algebraic operations.